# Refresh does not work anymore with angular-ui-router

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

Yesterday I switched from `ngRoute` to the `angular-ui-router` in my AngularJS application (Angular 1.4).

The problem I am facing is that if I reach a page through link/button everything works fine, but if I refresh the page (ctrl+r) the view is not shown.
Here's the code:

app.js

```
.config(['$stateProvider', '$locationProvider', 'ngClipProvider', "$urlRouterProvider", function($stateProvider, $locationProvider, ngClipProvider, $urlRouterProvider) { 
    $urlRouterProvider.when('/account', '/account/company');
    $urlRouterProvider.when('/', '/user_info');  
    var states = [
        {
            name: 'home',
            url: '/home',
            templateUrl: 'home/home.html'
        },
        {
            name: 'landing',
            url: '/',
            templateUrl: 'landing/landing.html',
        },
        .....
    ];
    states.forEach(function(state) {
        $stateProvider.state(state);
    });
    ngClipProvider.setPath("bower_components/zeroclipboard/dist/ZeroClipboard.swf");

    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
}]).
run(['$rootScope', '$location', 'Session', '$routeParams', 'store', '$route', "$urlRouter", function($rootScope, $location, Session, $routeParams, store, $route, $urlRouter){
    $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function(event, next) {
        if (typeof(next) !== 'undefined') {
            if (store.get('userId') !== null && (next.$$route.originalPath.indexOf('login') > 0 || next.$$route.originalPath.indexOf('signup') > 0 || next.$$route.originalPath.indexOf('accountant_sign_up') > 0 || next.$$route.originalPath.indexOf('partner_sign_up') > 0 || next.$$route.originalPath == '/')) {
                $location.path('/home');
            }

            if (typeof $route.routes[next.$$route.originalPath].data == "undefined") {
                console.log('skipped needAuth');
            } else {
                if ($route.routes[next.$$route.originalPath].data.needAuth) {
                    if (store.get('userId') == null){
                        event.preventDefault();
                        $location.path('/login');
                    }
                }

                if ($route.routes[next.$$route.originalPath].data.noBackground) {
                    var el = document.getElementById('main-background');
                    el.className += ' company-background';
                    $rootScope.random = null
                } else {
                    $('.company-background').css('background-image', "url('')");
                    $rootScope.random = Math.floor((Math.random() * 4) + 1);
                }
            }
        } else {
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    });
}]).
```

Am I missing something?

EDIT:

This is my express.js server configuration:

```
app.all('/*', function(req, res) {
    res.sendfile('app/index.html');
});
```

I tried also with

```
app.get('/*', function(req, res) {
    res.sendfile('app/index.html');
});
```

The application is still not showing the view when refreshed.

Comment: Can you add plnkr or fiddle for same?

Answer (score 0):

your problem is with server configurations.

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
```

You remove hashtag from url by this row. When you refresh the page, your host try to reach a file or folder as you define in your browser url. You should make a rewrite path method to reach `index.html` on your server or your local server.

Example for express server:

```
app.route('/*')
    .get(function(req, res) {
      res.sendfile(app.get('appPath') + '/index.html');
    });
```

Comment: I updated my questions with my server configuration code!

Comment: @ste you can use the method in the answer.